# Using the same kernel instance for more works

Tags: opencl

After i call clEnqueueNDRangeKernel using one cl_kernel instance can i use the same instance to enqueue an other task before the execution of the first one is finished? 
Or i need to instantiate an other cl_kernel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes this should be possible. If you enqueue a kernel a copy of the kernel state is enqueued. otherwise you wouldn't be able to modify the kernel args until the kernel command finishes execution. but i agree that this is not specified very clearly.